# Drupal 7 Block View include File

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I have a rather newbie question, I am following a Drupal 7 module examples, specifically an ajax wizard form. All form creation / manipulation is included in ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc which when is called in file attribute:

```
// A classic multi-step wizard, but with no page reloads.
  // See ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc.
  $items['examples/ajax_example/wizard'] = array(
    'title' => 'Wizard (with graceful degradation)',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('ajax_example_wizard'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    **'file' => 'ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc',**
    'weight' => 7,
  );
```

Next i would like to create a block which will be included in my template. It seems that i cant include a file attribute in block_view function. How can I do that?
Note: If I include all fuctions of ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc in .module file then my block works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @anil sagar said is correct. i think you are misunderstanding how `hook_menu()` functions. Remember, `hook_menu()` "enables modules to register paths in order to define how URL requests are handled." a block doesn't really register a path as it is part of the content of a node (content, article, blog, whatever). Hopefully that part makes some sense... let me know if it doesn't.

So you don't necessarily need the `hook_menu()` function for blocks (although exceptions can always been seen). Again, you'll need to write your code in your `my_cool_block.module` using the above stated hooks `hook_block_info()` and `hook_block_view()`.

however, you could `include` a file that has other custom module specific code in there. i tend to write my code with drupal hooks always in the `my_module.module` file. any supporting code i write either in a class or static class

Comment: Hi, Now I think that my question is not clear at all. I not disagree with @anil sagar nor with you. I know how hook_menu() works and I don't want to register any path nor to have hook_menu() (I used it as an example). What I am asking is: I like to have my source code to be in separate files 1: .module- where my hooks are living and 2:ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc - where I have my code for form generation etc. If you see in hook_menu() example above there is an attribute "file"=>blabla.inc, I cant find similar attribute in block_view() or block_info(). Hope now its clear, thanks

Comment: for a block, put your supporting source code in another file and simply include it in your `.module`. however, you should put `hook_block_info()` and `hook_block_view` in your `.module` file for drupal purposes. again, any supporting functions can be in another file. this is nothing new in php. as for the `file` key, this key does not exist for `hook_block_info()`. its only apart of `hook_menu()`. check the api again under return values for `hook_block_info()`. anything in bold is what key you can set for that assoc array.

Comment: Ok, since I saw a file key in hook_menu() I thought it is available in hook_block_info() and/or hook_block_view, which seems to be more drupal way to include any file. Thanks, I will stick with plain php way

Comment: no problem. i know the `key => value` stuff for drupal can be a little hard to wrap your head around (at least for me it can be). maybe you could suggest this to the drupal community for enhancement?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such an attribute in block_view function, but you can always use something like that (assuming that you have already implemented hook_block_info() and you have defined your own MYBLOCKDELTA):

```
function MYMODULENAME_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'MYBLOCKDELTA':
      $block['subject'] = t('This is my block');
      module_load_include('inc', 'MYMODULENAME', 'my_inc_file');
      $block['content'] = myblock_contents($delta);
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Then define function myblock_contents($delta) in your my_inc_file.inc in MYMODULENAME module folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please find answers for your question.

- You can create a block using [hook_block_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view($delta = '')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)
- Hooks should be written in .module file not in any other files inside module.
- So, create two functions in your.module file which will implement above two hooks to expose a custom block from module.
- You need to enable the block you created using administer blocks page.
- If you want to embed your block using code any where you can use below code !

  $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
  print render($block);

Hope it clarifies you !

Comment: Hi, perhaps my question is not clear. I already did what you correctly suggested meaning my hooks are in .module file, but the function for the form creation is in another file (ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc). If you see the above code there is an "file" attribute which includes the above file during menu creation. I hope to find similar attribute for the block, but cant find it.